# How can I install intel HD graphic driver with kernel 3.14.44

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics

I want to get a Intel graphic driver.
there are no support of intel, but I get intel-linux-graphics installer_1.0.7-0intel1_i386 and install && run
it gave me "Checking if Intel graphics card available... OK
Retrieving information from 01.org... Failed"

How can I install graphic driver?!

Thank you

Environment
- Ubuntu 14.04
- kernel 3.14.44( patch with xenomai)
- intel i3-skylake

lspci -nnk | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1912] (rev 06)

Comment: This sounds like a simple network error while running a tool that talks to a remote site.

Comment: 'Retrieving information from 01.org... Failed'  tells you your package-manger couldn't download from the site.  Try pointing a browser there & see the package exists (it may not anymore); or it was simply 'down' the moment you tried & is back up.  Something in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` etc. told it to check there so it did. Check your sources for errors (esp. if non-original [canonical/ubuntu] sites), point to another mirror, or just download it yourself then `dpkg -i` install it.

Comment: I do not know what is "patch with xenomai". But you may want to try newer driver from official Ubuntu repository - it is in `xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-xenial` package.

Comment: Typically this happens when people miss the part about adding signatures *before* using the Intel tool. Scroll down in the same page you downloaded it from and you'll see. Proceed according to the instructions and then simply run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. No need to ever run the GUI tool from Intel (it already added the Intel's repo, all is missing is the signature for that repo, then apt can do the rest).

Comment: I installed the package xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-trusty  like sudo apt-get install  package-name and did sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. but everything is same. 
I mean pach with xenomai that I did kernel patch kernel3.14.44 to using xenomai and some programs, so I should use kernel 3.14.44.

Comment: at first time that installed Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 4.4.43, it works great with intel graphic driver.  but Ubuntu with kernel 3.14.44 show me the graphic like Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe(LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)